# Texture turn black on some Android devices

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting a problem with texture run on Samsung A6(2018).
used Unity 2018.3.9
On some other devices such as Samsung S7 it's work fine.
[Black texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9avEk.png)
I've tried disable anti aliasing, but it doesn't work
[texture information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl3fp.png)
[Quality settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpAdB.png)
Here is the expected result

Comment: only the elephant texture turn black in this case

Comment: give us more details on your textures, is it sprite? are mipmaps enabled?  what about the compression? what about graphic settings? what else have you tried?

Comment: ![Graphic settings](https://imgur.com/a/XMRtPLq) ![Graphic settings](https://imgur.com/a/GMeikVh).

Comment: hello, i just update quality setings, texture information and the graphic setting in the comment

Comment: Please post text instead of image. Not only most image hosting websites will sweep their files once in a while, but also it's not searchable by search engines. Aside the fact that these websites are blocked in random countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit->Player Settings->Other Settings
Under Rendering header uncheck **GPU Skinning**

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with water shader on Android and it got fixed by setting "Auto Graphics API" in "Project Settings" -> "Player" -> "Other"